# Is there a way to use dynamic value for the documents being monitored in Cloud Functions at deploy time?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

At the current project I am working on, the collections in Firestore are differentiated using a prefix of `staging` and `production` for different environments, e.g. `staging-onboards` and `production-onboards`. I am trying to create a Cloud Function Trigger for both of these collections like so.

```
exports.triggerSendNewOnboardReceiverEmail = functions
  .region('us-west2')
  .firestore.document(`staging-onboards/{id}`)
  .onWrite(someHandler)
```

What I want to change is the content inside `.document(...)`. I want to change the `staging` value to `production` and vice-versa depending on the value I set in my `.env` file, say the value of the key `ENVIRONMENT`. Unfortunately, it seems that during deploy time, the `.env` values are not read and I can't change the value dynamically using `.env` file. I tried looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#configure_behavior, but it didn't solve my problem.

Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to put those two subcollections under a unique document and use a wildcard for the subcollections.

Concretely, two subcollections named for example:

`onboards/onboards/staging/`
`onboards/onboards/production/`

and the following Cloud Function:

```
exports.triggerSendNewOnboardReceiverEmail = functions
  .region('us-west2')
  .firestore
  .document(`onboards/onboards/{env}/{id}`)
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

      const environment = context.params.env; // staging or production

      // ...
    });
```

The advantage of moving the two collections under a document as subcollections is that the Cloud Function is not triggered for any new document: If we do `.document(`{colllectionId}/{docId}`)` the CF will be triggered for any document in the DB.

Comment: Without introducing a new collection structure (which will cause us having to move production data, and updating code), is it possible to achieve what I described?

Comment: Yes, but the Cloud Function will be triggered for any document in the DB, since the "watched path" will be `.document(`{any_collection}/{any_document}`)`. You'll have to check if the document that triggered it is an onboarding document by checking the value of `context.params.any_collection`